# Clone right clicked div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to clone div on which you right-click. Right-click opens the context menu, click **clone** option to clone it.

I am trying to achieve the same but don't know why it is not working, here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ersaurabh101/fvensq45/33/)

I have added code to clone the div on which we right clicked, I don't know why if it is working or not.

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu", "div", function(event) {
  $(".custom-menu")
    .show(100)
    .css({
      top: event.pageY + "px",
      left: event.pageX + "px"
    });

  alert("right clicked");
  event.preventDefault();
  $("div.selected").removeClass("selected");
  $("div.selected").addClass("selected");
  return false;
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
  $(".selecteddiv").removeClass("selecteddiv");
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});

$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    case "first":
      alert("clone button clicked");

                if($("div.selected").hasClass('selected')) {
        var clonned = $(this).clone();
              clonned.removeClass('selected');
             clonned.insertAfter($(this));
          }

      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}


.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.custom-menu li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #4679BD;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" style=" padding:20px; ">

    <div class="col-md-12 context_image">
        <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/ferrari/ferrari_PNG10680.png" class="imgsen-117 sim-row-edit">
    </div>

    <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 smalltxt20-l">Why is building with Variant so darn fun and dead-easy?
    </div>

    <div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 smalltxt">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam,
        eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 smalltxt context_menu context_link">
        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="btntst-b">LEARN MORE</a>
    </div>

</div>

<ul class='custom-menu'>
    <li data-action="first">Clone</li>
    <li data-action="second">Remove</li>
    <li data-action="third">Edit</li>
    <li data-action="fourth">Action</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no any code written in your shared code to create copy of element and append in the page, you are just printing right click menu and getting the event. See https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: on right click, 1. the border color is also not coming, i have added that code atleast

Comment: added the code to clone, problem is on right click it is not giving the border, neither it is cloaning

Answer (score 0):

i just given an id to your image

```
<img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/ferrari/ferrari_PNG10680.png" class="imgsen-117 sim-row-edit" id="img1">
```

when clicked on the clone option the below code creates the duplicate of the same image with id as "img2"

```
var div = document.getElementById('img1'); 
clone = div.cloneNode(true);  
clone.id = "img2";
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

Comment: Please dont give any extra id or class, this has to be handled only by selecting the div by right clicking on it, update jsfiddle and code in the question, please check - problem is on right click it is not giving the border, neither it is cloaning

Comment: On right click tm just showing border for LEARN MORE link. You can change that to the clicked element   http://jsfiddle.net/fvensq45/63/

Answer (score 0):

I added comments where I changed your JS code, and finally `#clonedContent` is just a div with that id. please check this,

```
 var clickedElement = ''; // I defined variable here
 $(document).on("contextmenu","div", function(event) {

     $(".custom-menu").show(100).
    css({
      top: event.pageY + "px",
      left: event.pageX + "px"
    });

 clickedElement  = $(this); // add your clicked element here
 event.preventDefault()
 $("div.selected").removeClass('selected');
                $("div.selected").addClass('selected');
                return false;


 })

     $(document).on("mouseup", function() {

        $(".selecteddiv").removeClass('selecteddiv');
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);

      });

      $(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
      switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
      case "first":
      $(clickedElement).clone().appendTo('#clonedContent'); // clone to a new dev
      break;
      }

      });
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6p2qzhn/) I have edited.

Comment: when you right click why it is nt giving the border of red color as i have added it, can u please check..if it will work i can see what is going to be cloned

Comment: and please dont append to clonedcontent div rther just append below the clicked div

Comment: `clickedElement  = $(this); // add your clicked element here` this is causing problem, you must use something like `div.seleted` , here is updated with color selection -http://jsfiddle.net/ersaurabh101/g6p2qzhn/7/  , you canupdate this one

Comment: @user2828442 do you want me to change the `$(this)` ?

Comment: @user2828442 actually `$(this)` means the exact the same selected `div`. What is the problem that cause with that ? and please mark this as answer if this answer helps you to solve your problem.